# Django testing a DeleteView

Tags: django, unit-testing

So in a DeleteView, the GET request returns a confirmation page, and a simple POST request with no fields except for the `csrf_token` actually gets the DeleteView to delete the object, upon which the user gets redirected to the `success_url`.

How can I test this functionality? In my `myclass_confirm_delete.html` file, I basically have:

```
<form action="{% url 'remove_myclass' object.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to remove {{ object.name }}?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

where `{% url 'remove_myclass' object.id %}` is the URL of the same exact page. It works in my browser. When I click "Yes," it redirects me to the success page, and the `myclass` object is removed from the database.

Now I am trying to test this automatically with unit tests. I basically try

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('remove_myclass', args=(myobject.id,)), follow=True)
self.assertContains(response, 'Are you sure you want to remove') # THIS PART WORKS
self.client.post(reverse('remove_myclass', args=(myobject.id,)), follow=True)
self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('myclass_removed'), status_code=302) # FAILS; status code is 200
```

If I try `print response`, I get the same exact response as when I had used the GET request.

It seems like while unit testing, no matter what kind of data I try to send in the POST request, it still gets treated as a GET request...

My class-based view:

```
class MyclassDelete(DeleteView):
    model = myclass
    success_url = '/myclass-removed/'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, this is because you're forgetting to assign the `post` request to `response`, so you're checking the same response twice.

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('remove_myclass', args=(myobject.id,)), follow=True)
self.assertContains(response, 'Are you sure you want to remove') # THIS PART WORKS

post_response = self.client.post(reverse('remove_myclass', args=(myobject.id,)), follow=True)
self.assertRedirects(post_response, reverse('myclass_removed'), status_code=302)
```

This should do the trick.

Also, just a tip, trying to assert more than once per unit test is considered bad practice when unit testing. Instead try to break it up so that one test tests the `GET` and on test tests the `POST`.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestDifferentRequestMethods(TestCase):

    def test_my_get_request(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('remove_myclass', args=(myobject.id,)), follow=True)
        self.assertContains(response, 'Are you sure you want to remove') # THIS PART WORKS

    def test_my_post_request(self):
        post_response = self.client.post(reverse('remove_myclass', args=(myobject.id,)), follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(post_response, reverse('myclass_removed'), status_code=302)
```

This makes for easier debugging and could save sometimes when stumbling onto these kinds of troubles!

**UPDATE** realized that I hadn't completed with a nice class to encompass the tests.

Comment: Oh gosh, don't know how I missed that I didn't reassign anything to response! And thanks a lot for the tip about asserting only once per unit test -- I seriously had no idea before!

Comment: Getting into TDD takes a lot of practice. I would recommend "Effective Unittesting - a guide for Java Developers" even though we're python developers this book helped me a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I will definitely look into it :)

Comment: I am trying to do this same thing with my tests, but it is not redirecting because the form is not bound without sending any data to it. Not sure how to mock this in my test to get it to pass.